# Matching node property against collection of sub strings in Neo 3.4.7

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Given a list of strings as an input parameter, I need to find all nodes, where the property nodeName *contains* one of the input parameter strings.

**Partial solution so far:**

```
MATCH (nodes:NodeLabel)
  WHERE any(x IN nodes.nodeName WHERE x IN ['string part I', 'string part II', 'string part III', 'string part IV'])
RETURN nodes;
```

**Missing magic:**

```
... WHERE node.nodeName IN ~ ['string part I', 'string part II', ...]
```

Actually, I’m unable to convince `IN` to go along with `CONTAINS` or a regular expression `=~ '.*substring.*'` for a case-insensitive match. Can you please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MATCH (nodes:NodeLabel)
WHERE ANY (x IN ['string part I', 'string part II', 'string part III', 'string part IV'] WHERE nodes.nodeName =~ x) 
RETURN nodes
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Works magnificent! Thank you @MichaelSimons.